# Redis PubSub message order in cluster is not guaranteed?

Tags: redis

Is the message order of pubsub messages in a redis cluster in any way guaranteed?

We are using a Redis cluster (v3.2.8) with 5 master nodes, each with one slave connected & we noticed that we sometimes get pubsub messages in wrong order when publishing to one specific master for one specific channel and being subscribed to slave nodes for that channel.

I could not find any statements related to *pubsub message order* in *cluster* on redis.io nor on the redis-github repo.

Comment: Redis now supports a new datatype called Redis Streams. Almost all uses of pub/sub are easier to implement using Redis Streams as they support resuming from any point in time and don't lose messages during disconnections: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/streams/

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if you are using PUBLISH, then it is blocking and returns only after messages have been delivered, so yes the order is guaranteed.

There are 2 problematic cases that I see: Pipelining and Client disconnection.

#### Pipelining

From the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining)

> While the client sends commands using pipelining, the server will be forced to queue the replies, using memory.

So, if a queue is used, the order should be guaranteed.

#### Client disconnection

I can't find it in the documentation, but if the client is not connected or subscribed when the message is published, then it wont receive anything. So in this case, there is no guarantee.

If you need to persist messages, you should use an a list instead.

Comment: thanks for you reply.

we are not using pipeling nor did we notice disconnects. Also disconnects could only lead to message loss and not to message-out-of-order.

wrt >returns only after messages have been delivered
I think this might be true only if subscribe command was issued to same node as publish command. Otherwise the node would need to wait until all nodes in the cluster delivered the message to all their connected clients.

Comment: "need to wait" yes, this is exactly what happens. That's why you have the option of pipelining commands to speed up your processing.

Comment: My opinion, not a definitive answer though, is that @sebuseba has found something meaningful. It would be better to move this discussion to the mailing list or open an issue in the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @ItamarHaber, I opened [this issue](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4122) in the repo.

Comment: Yep, saw that ;)